# Put data from database to text file

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a text file that contain for example :

```
The Fulton County Grand Jury said Friday an investigation.
The jury further said in term-end presentments that the City Executive Committee.
etc..
```

I have a table of dictionary of words on data base for example :

```
==========================
= id =    word  =  type  =
==========================
= 1  =  country = nn-tl  =
= etc...                 =
==========================
```

I have to search the same words of my text file with words on dictionary on database and take the type of that same words and then add them type to my text file with format `words/type`, so the final result must be :

```
The/at Fulton/np-tl County/nn-tl Grand/jj-tl Jury/nn-tl said/vbd Friday/nr an/at investigation/nn ./.
etc..
```

here's the code :
connection.php

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","peri");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
   trigger_error('Connection failed: '.$db->error);
}
```

the main program :

```
require_once 'connection.php';
$file  = "C:/AppServ/www/dictionary/text.txt";
$lines = file($file);
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line) {
     $parse = explode(' ', $line);  
     $query = $db->query("SELECT typeword FROM dictionary WHERE words = $parse");
     $result = $query->fetch_object();
      echo $parse '/' $result";
}
```

but it gives me error message `Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object`
plese help me, thank you :)

Comment: Try `("SELECT typeword FROM dictionary WHERE words = '".$parse."'")`

Comment: You have a syntax here in `echo $parse '/' $result";`

Comment: $parse is array, will it work, anyway?

Comment: @nevermind no, it doesn't work. how to make it work ?

Comment: @user3714179, is every word from text file inside 'dictionary' table, does it have its type? If not found - what should be printed? P.S. Is word in dictionary in exact same form, e.g. 'The' - uppercase?

Comment: @nevermind yes, every word has its type, word in dictionary has no exact form, some begin with uppercase and some begin with lowercase

Comment: i thought - is every word from text file in dictionary too? e.g. if one word from txt file is not found in database, what to print?

Comment: @nevermind no, if not found, just not print anything, for example if 'an' not found just print `an / `

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have dictionary table with fields: id, word, type, and your example text file, this could be solution (maybe you will need few tweaks here and there!):

```
$file  = "text.txt";



$lines = file($file);
foreach($lines as  $line) {
     $parse = explode(' ', $line);
     foreach ($parse as $word) {  

     //replace dot in last word in line
     $word_fix=str_replace('.','',$word);

     $query ="SELECT type FROM dictionary WHERE word = '$word_fix'";
     $result = $db->query($query);
   if($res = $result->fetch_object()) {

       echo $word.'/'.$res->type.' ';
   }

   else {
         echo $word.' /'.' ';
   }
     }
}
```

P.S. probably you have to replace: ,!?... to match word from database...